# Get specific column in array

Tags: php, arrays

i want to get table in array look to this code and you well get my idea

```
$blacklist = explode(',','Emad,Khaled');
        if(empty($name) or empty($account) or empty($comment)){
            include "tpl/error.php";

        }elseif(in_array($account, $blacklist)){
        echo "band";
        }else{ 
        echo "";}
```

i want to get column 'account' inside this code

```
$blacklist = explode(',','Emad,Khaled');
```

to be like this

```
$blacklist = explode(',','::1,::1');
```

i hope that you got my idea

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty much like `phpmyadmin`. Are you trying to expand its functionality?

Comment: no no 
i want to use it on page to allow some users to add and some other to block them